# Uninstalling Ubuntu (without WUBI)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, uninstall

I have Windows, and I wanted to install Ubuntu.
I accidentally installed it without WUBI.
Now I can't uninstall it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Try to explain in a more detailed way what you did.

Comment: Do you have **dual boot** when you turn on the PC ? You want to uninstall the Ubuntu now?

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall Ubuntu using Ubuntu

This method can be used when we installed the Windows and Ubuntu dual-boot partitions and autonomous. First, ENTER  in Ubuntu and downloaded, depending on which version you have installed Ubutnu, this tiny application:

Download ms-sys to Ubuntu 32-bit[32 bit](http://wiki.ubuntu-it.org/AmministrazioneSistema/RipristinoMbrWindows?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=ms-sys_2.1.0-1_i386.deb)

Download ms-sys to Ubuntu 64-bit[64 bit](http://wiki.ubuntu-it.org/AmministrazioneSistema/RipristinoMbrWindows?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=ms-sys_2.1.0-1_amd64.deb)

Download ms-sys to Powerpc

then, install it (just double-click on the downloaded file and follow the indications).
 after  which if  you only have one hard disk, open the terminal (Applications / Accessories / Terminal) and paste this line:

**sudo ms-sys-w / dev / sda**

finally you can delete the partitions of ubuntu with Gparted
or other utility under Windows